# Flexible width on items that are absolutely positioned

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm looking at creating a grid for a day view of a calendar, where the items are vertically positioned and sized according to their start and end times. If an agenda item doesn't overlap with anything else, its width will span the full width of the column; however, if items overlap, they split the width between them. Example images below:

[Full-width items, no overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUTgh.png)

[Overlapping items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4ixl.png)

Clearly, this can all be calculated using Javascript with full knowledge of all the meetings at once.  However, I'm wondering if there's an elegant CSS solution to handle this, where the code needs to only provide the vertical position and height?

I ask because I'm hoping to organize my React code such that each grid box only needs to know the data for its own agenda item, keeping good encapsulation; rather than needing to pass in a bunch of data (pre-processed or not) about other items.

Comment: Can you clarify the question and create an MCVE? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect use case for flexbox. Which also plays nicely with React.

Bootstrap V4 can be used with flexbox. Another good option if you are using PostCSS is lost grid.

Comment: Flexbox doesn't work well with absolutely-positioned elements; at least, not in the way I'm trying to get it to work. Each item in the grid is dynamically positioned at an absolute vertical position, so I'm not sure if lost grid would help either.

Comment: Why absolute? Flexbox doesn't mean you need absolute, unless there is something not mentioned in the question